# On Finding Coin Jams

Tags: python, algorithm, programming-challenge, random

The problem can be found [here](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/6254486/dashboard#s=p2) and is essentially asking us to generate *J* many numbers containing *N* many digits, where these digits have to be either 0 or 1. The catch is that the these numbers that we generate have to be composite when interpreted as being written in base *i*, where *i* ranges from 2 to 10, inclusive. Furthermore, these digits have to begin and end with a 1.

My solution was to randomly generate candidate numbers and test for compositeness across the bases. However, I am wondering if perhaps there is a better way to solve the problem (with the interest of speed)? For perusal, my code is as follows (note that I believe it to be correct, but slowy):

```
import sys
import random

# converts a list of 1's and 0's interpreted in base i, to base 10 equivalent
def base_i_to_base_10(binary, i):
    return sum([binary[j]*(i**(len(binary)-j-1)) for j in range(len(binary))])

# checks primality of a number
# if prime, return -1
# if composite, return the divisor that indicated so
def isPrime(num):
    for i in range(2,int(num**0.5)+1):
        if num%i==0:
            return i
    return -1

# Function to check if a number (whose digits are 0 and 1) is prime
# Primality is tested by converting the number into bases 2 through 10
# If prime, we return []; representing that no divisors exist
# If composite, we return a ['some divisor'] as proof
def notPrime(binary):
    theFactors = []
    # iterates over bases 2 through 10
    for i in range(2,11):
        num = base_i_to_base_10(binary, i) # number after converting to base i
        divisor = isPrime(num)
        if divisor==-1:
            return [] # the number was prime in base i
        else:
            theFactors += [divisor] # the number is not prime in base i
    return theFactors # the number is composite in bases 2 through 10

# Reads in how many test cases there are
caseNums = int(sys.stdin.readline().strip("\n"))

case = 0 # initalize case count to zero

# read lines from standard input
for line in sys.stdin:
    case += 1
    # each line contains two numbers
    # N is the number of digits the binary number contains
    # by binary we mean made up of 1's and 0's, and not necessarily in base 2
    # J is the number of binary digits that are not prime in any of the bases
    # 2 through 10 and begin and end with 1, that we would like to generate
    N, J = [int(i) for i in line.strip('\n').split(' ')]

    print "Case #{}:\n".format(case) # print out test case number

    valid = [] # list of valid binary numbers satisfying the requiremnts
    seen = [] # list of binary numbers we've considered already

    # randomly generate a candidate binary number
    binary = [1]+[int(random.random() > 0.5) for i in range(N-2)]+[1]

    # A list of divisors, one from each base 2 through 10
    # If the number is not prime in atleast one of the above bases, divs = []
    divs = notPrime(binary) 

    # while we haven't generated J many valid binary numbers, keep searching
    while (len(valid)<J):

        # if the randomly generated binary number isn't one we've seen already
        # and if it is prime across all bases 2 through 10
        # record the binary number as valid
        if ( not (binary in seen) and len(divs)==9):
            # dispay binary number and some of its divisors
            num = ''.join([str(i) for i in binary]) + " "
            for i in divs:
                num += str(i)+" "
            num = num.strip(' ')
            print num

            valid += [binary] # mark binary number as valid

        seen += [binary] # mark the binary number as already seen

        # generate a new binary number to consider, and some of its divisors
        binary = [1]+[int(random.random() > 0.5) for i in range(N-2)]+[1]
        factors = notPrime(binary)
```

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: Note about variable naming: It has been mentioned in chat that the OP (Ragnar) did a mistake while renaming variables and in posting the question here: `factors = notPrime(binary)` should be `divs = notPrime(binary)`, as pointed out in the answer by Veedrac.

Answer (score 7):

Your code is mostly slow because it's broken. You write

```
factors = notPrime(binary)
```

where you meant

```
divs = notPrime(binary)
```

(although I'd be tempted to rename them the other way, so they're all `factors`).

Your loop looks like

```
binary = ...
factors = ...
while predicate:
    ...
    binary = ...
    factors = ...
```

This is better as

```
while True:
    binary = ...
    factors = ...
    if not predicate:
        break
    ...
```

Don't add randomness where determinism will do. You can iterate through binary numbers like

```
from itertools import product
for binary in product((0, 1), repeat=N-2):
    binary = (1,) + binary + (1,)
```

You can remove `seen` when doing this.

Put the code inside a `main` function; it's not only faster by avoiding global variables, but it's nicer too.

PyPy makes this much faster, brining it from about 50 seconds with CPython to 1.5 with PyPy for input `1\n16 50`.

You formatting is really inconsistent. Stick to PEP 8. Invest in better names, like `num_results` instead of `J`.

Some of your documentation is bad, like

```
case = 0 # initalize case count to zero
```

These should just be removed.

Some, like

```
# iterates over bases 2 through 10
for i in range(2, 11):
```

are made useless by just using good naming:

```
for base in range(2, 11):
```

Also, don't write `the_thing`. It's just `thing`.

`base_i_to_base_10` doesn't convert to base 10. It converts to an integer, which does not have a base (it's just a number). It should be called something like `num_from_digits` and its second argument should be `base`, usable by name.

`is_prime` doesn't check if a number is prime. It should be called `divisor` or somesuch. Instead of `-1`, it should return `num`, since that's a valid divisor of the number. Or maybe `None` if you don't like that.

`not_prime` doesn't check if a value is not prime. Instead, try `bases_not_prime`. Better would be `prime_in_base` which you then `map` over `range(2, 11)`:

```
not any(prime_in_base(binary, base) for base in range(2, 11))
```

`sys.stdin.readline()` is just `raw_input()`.

`num_from_digits` is much simpler as an iterative form:

```
def num_from_digits(binary, base):
    num = 0
    for digit in binary:
        num *= base
        num += digit
    return num
```

Comments above functions should normally be docstrings:

```
def num_from_digits(binary, base):
    """
    Convert an iterable of digits to its represented number,
    most significant digit first.
    """
    ...
```

Rather than `case += 1`, just `enumerate` `sys.stdin`:

```
for case, line in enumerate(sys.stdin):
```

Then

```
[int(i) for i in line.strip('\n').split(' ')]
```

is nicer as

```
map(int, line.split())
```

`found` isn't really useful; just store `num_found`.

I would personally move some more of this out to an iterator that `yield`s results. This seperates some of the logic out.

So here's a first-pass clean-up:

```
import sys
from itertools import islice, product

def num_from_digits(digits, base):
    """
    Convert an iterable of digits to its represented number,
    most significant digit first.
    """
    num = 0
    for digit in digits:
        num *= base
        num += digit
    return num

def divisor(num):
    """
    Return the smallest divisor greater than one
    of a natural number.
    """
    for i in range(2, int(num ** 0.5) + 1):
        if num % i == 0:
            return i
    return num

def prime_in_base(digits, base):
    """
    Return whether the digits are prime when interpreted
    in a given base.
    """
    num = num_from_digits(digits, base)
    return divisor(num) == num

def jamcoins(num_binary_digits):
    """
    A jamcoin is a string of N ≥ 2 digits with the following properties:

    * Every digit is either 0 or 1.
    * The first digit is 1 and the last digit is 1.
    * If you interpret the string in any base between 2 and 10, inclusive,
      the resulting number is not prime.

    - https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/6254486/dashboard#s=p2
    """
    for digits in product((0, 1), repeat=num_binary_digits-2):
        digits = (1,) + digits + (1,)

        if not any(prime_in_base(digits, base) for base in range(2, 11)):
            yield digits

def main():
    # Number of test cases; not needed
    _ = raw_input()

    for i, line in enumerate(sys.stdin):
        print "Case #{}:\n".format(i)

        num_binary_digits, num_results = map(int, line.split())
        for digits in islice(jamcoins(num_binary_digits), 0, num_results):
            print ''.join(map(str, digits)),
            for base in range(2, 11):
                num = num_from_digits(digits, base)
                print divisor(num),
            print

main()
```

The slowest part of the code is probably `divisor`, which involves a prime check. There are much faster ways to do this, like precalculating with a prime sieve.